# Sorting charts(bargraph, table) on basis of month logic and not on basis of alphabetically

Tags: sorting, charts

I made bar charts and table from data but i am not able to sort x axis of bar chart and table data on basis of month. i clicked on sort bars ,but it is sorting on basis of spelling of months and not on basis of month name logic. i even applied sort query but still its not reflecting.
my query of both charts are

table query --->
SELECT CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR) AS `Year`,
left(date_format(OPEN_TIME, '%M'), 3) AS `Month`,
CASE
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '1' THEN '1 - Critical'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '2' THEN '2 - High'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '3' THEN '3 - Medium'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '4' THEN '4 - Low'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '5' THEN '5 - Minor'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '6' THEN 'n/a'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY IS NULL THEN 'Unassigned'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS `Severity`,
`NUMBER` AS `NUMBER`,
count(`NUMBER`) AS `COUNT(NUMBER)`
FROM tablexyz
WHERE CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR) IN ('2023')
GROUP BY CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR),
left(date_format(OPEN_TIME, '%M'), 3),
CASE
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '1' THEN '1 - Critical'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '2' THEN '2 - High'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '3' THEN '3 - Medium'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '4' THEN '4 - Low'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '5' THEN '5 - Minor'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '6' THEN 'n/a'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY IS NULL THEN 'Unassigned'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END,
`NUMBER`
ORDER BY `COUNT(NUMBER)` DESC
LIMIT 10000;

and my bargraph query --->
SELECT left(date_format(OPEN_TIME, '%M'), 3) AS `Month`,
CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR) AS `Year`,
count(CASE
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '1' THEN '1'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '2' THEN '1'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '3' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '4' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '5' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '6' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE NULL
END) AS `COUNT(Severity_1-2)`,
count(CASE
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '1' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '2' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '3' THEN '1'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '4' THEN '1'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '5' THEN '1'
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY = '6' THEN NULL
WHEN BS_SECURITY_SEVERITY IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE NULL
END) AS `COUNT(Severity_3-5)`
FROM tablexyz
WHERE CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR) IN ('2023')
GROUP BY left(date_format(OPEN_TIME, '%M'), 3),
CONVERT(YEAR(OPEN_TIME),CHAR)
ORDER BY `COUNT(Severity_1-2)` DESC
LIMIT 1000;

how can we sort charts on basis of month logic

i was sorting table and bargraph on basis of month

i applied sort option indiviually on charts and even tried sort bar option in cutomised section
still its sorting on basis of month spelling(alphabetically) , not on basis of month logic